# Watson Conversation Service - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials

Tags: java, ibm-cloud, watson-conversation

I've tried to access the Watson Conversation Service via a Java Application. Therefore I created the Service on Bluemix an wrote a small Application.

```
package de.kkh.comp.WatsonDemo;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

import com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.conversation.v1.ConversationService;
import com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.conversation.v1.model.MessageRequest;
import com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.conversation.v1.model.MessageResponse;

public class App {

private static final String USERNAME = "{USERNAME}";
private static final String PASSWORD = "{PASSWORD}";
private static final String WORKSPACE_ID = "{WORKSPACE_ID}";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ConversationService service = new ConversationService(ConversationService.VERSION_DATE_2017_02_03);
    service.setUsernameAndPassword(USERNAME, PASSWORD);

    MessageRequest newMessage = new MessageRequest.Builder().inputText("Hallo").context(new HashMap<String,Object>()).build();

    MessageResponse response = service.message(WORKSPACE_ID, newMessage).execute();

    System.out.println(response);
}
}
```

I expect that i get a simple answer of the Watson Service.

If I run the Application I got an Not Authorized Exception, although i use the credentials which are given by Bluemix.

```
Aug 02, 2017 7:56:19 PM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFORMATION: --> POST https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/conversation/api/v1/workspaces/{WORKSPACE_ID}/message?version=2017-02-03 http/1.1 (39-byte body)
Aug 02, 2017 7:56:20 PM okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFORMATION: <-- 401 Not Authorized https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/conversation/api/v1/workspaces/{WORKSPACE_ID}/message?version=2017-02-03 (214ms, unknown-length body)
Aug 02, 2017 7:56:20 PM com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.service.WatsonService processServiceCall
SCHWERWIEGEND: POST https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/conversation/api/v1/workspaces/{WORKSPACE_ID}/message?version=2017-02-03, status: 401, error: Not Authorized
Exception in thread "main" com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.service.exception.UnauthorizedException: Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials
    at com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.service.WatsonService.processServiceCall(WatsonService.java:492)
    at com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.service.WatsonService$2.execute(WatsonService.java:254)
    at de.kkh.comp.WatsonDemo.App.main(App.java:26)
```

I haven't any clue why i got this Exception. Any Ideas?

Comment: Did you check for spelling errors? Capitalization? Did you use the right class, method or format? Add more details and try a google search or two.

Comment: I've copy-pasted the credentials, and the classes, methods, ... are as described in the Service API. I've googled, but couldn't find anything useful. That's why I'm asking. What details do you want to know?

Comment: Could it be  the API has changed? If we look at [the current version](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/java-sdk/blob/develop/conversation/src/main/java/com/ibm/watson/developer_cloud/conversation/v1/ConversationService.java#L95), the date string is +3 months newer then the library version you are running.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem solved.

I used a german location. Therefore the API-Endpoint needs to be https://gateway-fra.watsonplatform.net/conversation/api, instead of the Default-URL.

The Constructor of ConversationService uses the Default-URL, which is https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/conversation/api. To change the Endpoint it's necessary to call: 
`service.setEndPoint("https://gateway-fra.watsonplatform.net/conversation/api")`

After I did that, everthing worked fine.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem - my issue was, that the api URL I was calling was for the wrong location. For example, if you are using Germany, the correct API endpoint is: https://gateway-fra.watsonplatform.net/conversation/api

Comment: Sounds legit. You're right. I use a german location. 
I try that with another endpoint. Thank you.

Comment: Hey. I've changed the endpoint as you said. That worked well. Thank you for your help. :)

Comment: Glad I could help! :)